# Slide the slected code left in pycharm editor

Tags: python, pycharm, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to slide the code left by selected multiple lines in PyCharm editor.I remember *tab* is used for sliding right but is stuck how can we shift the code left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the lines you want to unindent and hit `Shift + Tab`.